# Deployment Fail Due to Time-Out

Tags: deployment, timeout, amazon-ec2

I'm newbie in AWS.

I've read the tutorial of Getting Started to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I deployed the sample application "My Elastic Beanstalk Sample Application" successfully.

However, whatever webapp, I try to deploy from scratch, fails with the same reason:
"Exceeded maximum amount time to wait for the application to become available. Setting environment Ready."

Additionally, the log records include following log:

"INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib"

I tried to many simple examples even the following one;

https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/elasticbeanstalk-sampleapp2.war

What is the key point that I miss, can anyone help me?